# How to wait for onChange event to set Value using react hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I want to access the value of `value` state variable inside `handleKeyDown` function. But, as I go on typing I notice that `value` is not set to the latest input value but the previous input state instead. I used `setTimeout` so that `handleChange` would be called first and `setValue()` function would change the value of `value` . And then changed value would be reflected inside `handleKeyDown` function.

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log("called handle changed");
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    console.log("called keydown");
    console.log(value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        onKeyDown={(e) => setTimeout(() => handleKeyDown(e), 0)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

`e.target.value` shows the latest and required value, but `value` itself shows the old value. How to wait until `handleChange` sets the value using `setValue` and use `value` in `handleKeyDown` ?

Comment: React state updates are asynchronously processed, you can't wait for them. Why can't `handleKeyDown` also use `e.target.value`? What is the use case/issue you are trying to solve for? BTW, using the `setTimeout` isn't working because the version of `handleKeyDown` is the one closing over the unupdated `value` state in callback scope, so even if the timeout was 10 minutes, it would still log the stale state value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the useRef hook for the current value

`

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const updatedValue = useRef("");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log("called handle changed");
    setValue(e.target.value);
    updatedValue.current = e.target.value;
  };

  const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    console.log("called keydown");
    console.log(updatedValue.current);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        onKeyDown={(e) => setTimeout(() => handleKeyDown(e), 0)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

`